How do I translate an image / scene with Ren'Py?
I need a certain picture to appear in the game when a certain language is enabled. I assume I'd need to write something like the following to do that:
if game.Language("english"):
    scene warning1b
else:
    scene warning1

How do I write this correctly? and is it possible?

According to the Ren'Py Preference Variables documentation, this can be done in the following manner:
if preferences.language == "english":
    scene warning1b
else:
    scene warning1


Awesome! If this solved your problem, consider marking this as the "Accepted Answer." I'd really appreciate it :)
